# Datetime received a naive datetime whereas I precised before the timezone

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-datetime

I am working a Django project. Here is my code :

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
currentperiod = Day.objects.get(enddate__gte=today.date(),
                                               startdate__lte=today.date())
```

And I got that message :

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Day.startdate received a naive datetime (2021-10-04 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s.%s received a naive datetime "
```

So I tried that :

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
today = pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris").localize(today, is_dst=None)
            currentperiod = Period.objects.get(enddate__gte=today.date(),
                                               startdate__lte=today.date())
```

But it does not work whereas I used pytz, I suppose it comes from `today.date()` but I don't know how to proceed further ...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: A `date` has no timezone info.

Comment: Are `enddate` and `startdate` `DateField`s, or `DateTimeField`s?

Comment: they are DateTimeField

Comment: what Django version do you use?

Comment: it is the version 2.1.2

Answer (score 1):

A `date` has no timezone info, hence that does not work by localizing. What you can do is truncate today and then add this as filtering:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
today = pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris").localize(today, is_dst=None)
today = today.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

currentperiod = Period.objects.get(
    startdate__lte=today,
    enddate__gte=today
)
```

If you want to check the `enddate` by the *end* of the day, then you can work with:

```
from datetime import timedelta

today = datetime.datetime.now()
today = pytz.timezone(&quot;Europe/Paris&quot;).localize(today, is_dst=None)
today = today.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

currentperiod = Period.objects.get(
    startdate__lte=today,
    enddate__gte=today + timedelta(days=1, microseconds=-1)
)
```